# Need to add newly added entry to new column for given xml using xsl

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

Hi I have a requirement where i need to add newly added information of child to a separate column.
I have complimented the same but facing some issues.
As of now newly added entries are getting added to same date and versioninfo column But I want this information to be added in separate column.

Any help is appropriated.

Thanks

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<DeviceHistory>
  <Part Name="ERUI_Touch_LEFT">
    <Details>
      <Date>2019-01-28</Date>
      <DeviceInfo>Firmware Version: -1</DeviceInfo>
       <Date>2019-01-29</Date>
      <DeviceInfo>Firmware Version: -2</DeviceInfo>
    </Details>
  </Part>
  <Part Name="ERUI_Touch_RIGHT">
    <Details>
      <Date>2019-01-30</Date>
      <DeviceInfo>Firmware Version: -1</DeviceInfo>
       <Date>2019-01-31</Date>
      <DeviceInfo>Firmware Version: -2</DeviceInfo>
    </Details>
  </Part>
</DeviceHistory>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0 "
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="Part[@Name]/Details">
  <html>
  <body> 

   <table-header> <xsl:value-of select ="../@Name"/></table-header>
  <table border="1" style="width:14cm">
    <tr bgcolor="lightgray" margin-top="10pt">
      <th>Date</th>
      <td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Date"/></td>   
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr bgcolor="lightgray">
      <th>VersionInfo</th>    
      <td>
       <td><xsl:apply-templates select="DeviceInfo"/></td>
    </td> 
    </tr>   
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As of now i am creating a table for each part.Every table will have two rows with Date and Version info and there respective information data in adjacent column.This xml file be getting updated on every hardware change. Whenever a new entry comes for same part i want to add this information in new column.

Comment: Can you show the expected output of your example XML?

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Please refer below link for expected and actual output.    https://imgur.com/a/fm1ri89

Comment: @michael.hor257k it worked Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0 "
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/DeviceHistory">
    <html>
        <body> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Part"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="Part">
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
    </h3>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Details/Date"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Version Info</th>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Details/DeviceInfo"/>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Date | DeviceInfo">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Applied to your example XML, the result will be:

```
<html><body>
<h3>ERUI_Touch_LEFT</h3>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<td>2019-01-28</td>
<td>2019-01-29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Version Info</th>
<td>Firmware Version: -1</td>
<td>Firmware Version: -2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<h3>ERUI_Touch_RIGHT</h3>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<td>2019-01-30</td>
<td>2019-01-31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Version Info</th>
<td>Firmware Version: -1</td>
<td>Firmware Version: -2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Rendered as:

[image]